# Result of a definite Integral

Tags: definite-integrals, solution-verification

I'm looking for the result of

> $$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos(x)^n \cos(nx)dx .$$

I got $\displaystyle \pi/2^n$ as a result. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Checking the cases $n = 0$ and $n = 1$ suggests it should be $\pi/2^{n-1}$.

Comment: Oh you are right, I didn't think of checking some cases for n. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can write

$$(\cos x)^n = \left(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\right)^n = \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} e^{i(n-2k)x}.$$

Assuming it known that

$$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{imx}\cos (nx)\,dx = 0$$

for $m \neq \pm n$, since the family $\{ \cos (nx) : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{\sin (nx) : n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$ is orthogonal, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} (\cos x)^n \cos (nx)\,dx &= \frac{1}{2^n}\int_0^{2\pi} \left(e^{inx} + e^{-inx}\right)\cos (nx)\,dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^2 (nx)\,dx\\
&= \frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}.
\end{align}$$